# Passing public variables to click event wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone explain me the difference between below 2 cases ?

When click button; label1 shows **12** but label is **0**.
By clicking button, I want to assign values to public variables and use them in MainWindow or in other classes.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label.Content = num1;
    }
     public int num1;

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
       num1 = 15;
       label1.Content = 12;   
    }    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s15J5.jpg)

Thank you,in advance..

Comment: I don't get what you ware tried to ask, could you please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a value type. When you assign a value-type variable to another value-type variable, the value is copied. For example:

```
int a = 4;
int b = a;
a = 2;

// a = 2
// b = 4
```

**EDIT:** If your goal is to be able to assign to a field from anywhere and have it update your label automatically, you can use a property:

```
private int num1;
public int Num1
{
    get
    {
        return num1;
    }
    set
    {
        num1 = value;
        Label.Content = num1;
    }
}

// Elsewhere

Num1 = 15; // Assign to the property rather than the field directly
```

Comment: Best possible answer. Public fields are extremely bad practice. Properties are the solution. Up-voted..

Comment: @AmmarSalman That depends on who you ask. While I agree with you, some would say that properties are bad practice as well, and that the real "best" solution is getter and setter methods.

Comment: C++ programmers would always suggest that. Anyway, getter and setter are the safest after all.. For static variables it is still better to use getter and setter..

Comment: @AmmarSalman I suppose, though I'm not sure what safety that getters/setters provide that a property couldn't do just as well. I mean, properties get compiled to getter and setter methods regardless.

Comment: Personally I do prefer properties as they produce better organized code. However, when dealing with static variables I tend to keep them private and use getter/setter.

Comment: @Abion47 Thank you very much for your response. It'll solve my problem. Actually I'm quite new in C# and previously, I used PLC programming and my mistake is I'm still confusing the system with it. It has scan cycle and when you change a public value, it changes in other points of program, as well. But it makes more sense,now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here,

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label.Content = num1; //Assigned to 0 as int don't have null
    }
     public int num1;
```

And in this,

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
       num1 = 15; //you set num1, not label.Content
       label1.Content = 12;   
    }
```

So, here is the solution.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {    
           num1 = 15; //you set num1, not label.Content
           label.Content = num1;
           label1.Content = 12;   
        }
```